# how to reduce file size of a word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I am having trouble reducing a word document size from 1.2kb to 512mb to upload to an online portfolio.

I have copy and pasted it into a new document, I have compressed it into a zip file, I have taken all images out, I have played around with font sizes, and I have had no luck at all. Any ideas how I can get it to 512mb.

Comment: 1.2 KB is already way smaller than 512 MB. Did you make a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Save it a txt, html or xml. Given that plain txt will wipe out every format that you have in your document, it will shrink the size of it.